# Calculate peaks in dataset using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset showing a datetime and a battery charge level;

```
| 2013-05-14 09:40:30 |      29 |
| 2013-05-14 09:41:31 |      24 |
| 2013-05-14 09:42:31 |      10 |
| 2013-05-14 09:43:33 |      5 |
| 2013-05-14 09:44:34 |      50 |   -> battery charge started
| 2013-05-14 09:50:35 |      70 |
| 2013-05-14 09:51:36 |      100 |  -> battery full 
| 2013-05-14 09:52:37 |      90 |
| 2013-05-14 09:53:37 |      75 |
| 2013-05-14 09:54:39 |      32 |
| 2013-05-14 09:55:39 |      19 |
| 2013-05-14 09:56:40 |      2 |
| 2013-05-14 09:54:39 |      42 |   -> battery charge started
| 2013-05-14 09:55:39 |      89 |
| 2013-05-14 09:56:40 |      100 | -> battery full 
| 2013-05-14 09:57:39 |      100 |
| 2013-05-14 09:58:39 |      99 |
```

I want to count how many times the battery was fully charged.. I can't simply count the 100%'s since sometimes (as you see at the bottom) I have multiple rows sometimes showing 100% (for up to several days depending on usage of the device). 
Anyone knows a way to count the peaks using mysql? So in the above example the result should be 2.. in the example the datetime is a bit condensed.. in reality is spans a week.

Comment: So, you want to count non-contiguous 100s?

Comment: How did time go backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT
    pit,
    IF(@oldcharge<>100 OR chargeperc<>100,@oldcharge:=chargeperc,101) AS charge
  FROM
    (SELECT @oldcharge:=0) AS init,
    charging
  ORDER BY pit
) AS baseview
WHERE charge=100;
```

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed82a/4/0)

Explanation:

- In the inner query we raise all charging values, that are 100 **and** come immediately after another 100 to 101
- In the outer query, we select those with 100, but not those with 101

Comment: Took a bit of tweaking, but yes.. this did the job. Thanks a lot!